# Swift unwraps value as nil when in closure but successfully unwraps elsewhere in code?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

So here is my code

```
func retrieveAndAssignHighScoreFromCloudKit() {
    let high = highScore
    database.fetchRecordWithID(getRecordID(high), completionHandler: { [weak self]
        (record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) in
        if error != nil {
            print(self!.highScore)
        // blah blah blah...
}
```

So in the first line of this function I am able to call highScore and assign it to something else but inside the closure Xcode is forcing me to use "self!." and in doing so somehow unwraps an optional even though my calling it prior shows me that it is not nil. I am really confused and there are a ton of basic questions about unwrapping optionals as nil but none that I've found seem to pertain to this.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Tried switching "weak" to "unowned" and I crash on the same line and get "Thread 3: EXC_BREAKPOINT" despite not having and breakpoints. This message is displayed in green on another screen and does not highlight that line

Comment: instead of `if error != nil`, use `if let error = error` since your error is optional, also, try `unowned self` instead of `weak self`

Comment: using "unowned" allowed me to not use any unwrapping but it still crashes my program on that line. it puts me to another panel saying "thread 2: EXC_BREAKPOINT" however I don't have any breakpoints

Comment: That probably mean something wrong with your `self`, it got deinitialized before the closure done executing, you should check its life time again

Answer (score 0):

Closures are not executed immediately.

When you pass a closure to the `fetchRecordWithID` method, you are telling it to execute that code when the method finishes fetching data, which can take time.

So far so good, right?

In the closure's capture list, you tell it to capture `self` as a `weak` reference. What's the purpose of this? To avoid a strong reference cycle, of course. If you don't, `self` holds a strong reference to the closure, and the closure holds a strong reference to `self`. As a result, both the closure and `self` will not be deinitialized.

A `weak` reference to `self` in the closure guarantees that `self` is deinitialized when the strong reference to the closure is broken.

I hope I've explained this well.

So now, let's say the strong reference to the closure is broken. As I said, `self` would be deinitialized as a result. After that, the thing finishes fetching data and it is now executing the `completionHandler` closure! Since `self` is already nil at this point, your app will crash when it reaches `print(self!.highScore)`.

**In other words, a weak reference to `self` implies that `self` *can be nil*. You need to unwrap it.**

EDIT:

Maybe images can explain this better. (black arrows are strong references, green arrows are weak ones)

At first, it's like this:

[image]

When the strong reference is broken...

[image]

self becomes nil:

[image]

You can simply do something like this:

```
if let score = self?.highScore {
    print(score)
    // blah blah blah
} else {
    // do something else, or nothing
}
```

Or just this:

```
print(self?.highScore)
```

Comment: Great. But what is the solution?

Comment: Okay I follow your explanation. The images were very helpful! I have two questions: I figured out that completely removing the "[weak self]" seems to make the code work. Does that mean I am leaving it as strong references? What exactly is the problem with not deinitializing them? Secondly what is the code for using the "[weak self]" and having it not crash? How can I keep it from deinitializing?

Comment: @lelephant You can remove `[weak self]` to make it not crash, but yes, this will create a strong reference cycle and might cause memory issues. The solution is kind of simple, just don't force-unwrap the optional. You can use optional binding or just a simple `?` to unwrap the optional value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `strong` reference when trying to use `self` like this:

```
func retrieveAndAssignHighScoreFromCloudKit() {
        let high = highScore
        database.fetchRecordWithID(getRecordID(high), completionHandler: { [weak self]
            (record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                print(strongSelf.highScore)
                // blah blah blah...
            }
        }
    }
```